# How to use associated data with the list finder?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I m creating options for my dropdown using find with list.
But i want to fetch the data of associated table.
Given below is my code

```
$users = $this->UserRoles
    ->find('list', [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
        'limit' => 200,
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'Users.first_name'
    ])
    ->where([
        'Users.status' => true,
        'Users.company_id' => $company_id,
        'UserRoles.role_id' => 4
    ]);
```

But it returns me null as output.

Comment: Whenever you have problems with associations, please also explain the association setup, I can only assume it's `UserRoles belongsTo Users`. Also please be a little more specific as to where exactly the `null` value occurs, is it `$users` that is `null`, or are the keys and/or values in the list `null`, or...?

Answer (score 1):

The example from the book has the `contain` query chained as follows:

`$query = $articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'author.name'
])->contain(['Authors']);`

So perhaps try:

`$users = $this->UserRoles
  ->find('list', [
      'limit' => 200,
      'keyField' => 'id',
      'valueField' => 'Users.first_name'
  ])
  ->contain(['Users'])
  ->where([
      'Users.status' => true,
      'Users.company_id' => $company_id,
      'UserRoles.role_id' => 4
 ]);`